# Spring-Boot: Jmx annotation not working in library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring-Boot application that just have a simple rest controller. On this controller, I added the jmx annotations @ManagedResource and @ManagedOperation and it is working fine. It is correctly exposed in Jmx.
This application depends on a "global-commons" library to share many basic functionality to all of our modules.

But if I add the same annotations to a class in this library, it is ignored!
And before you ask, yes the library is imported with the latest change.
There is no error or warning message in the logs.

I am configuring all my beans using an xml file. Both classes are beans defined in the same file.
One is a @RestController. The other one is a simple utility class.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the classes from the global-commons library as managed by Spring. As long as none of the classes in the library are managed by Spring, the annotions don't have any effect.

Comment: They are. Like I said both classes are defined in the same spring xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problems:
The bean that was not working was defined as an "inner" bean:

```
<bean id="imMetrics" class="com.imetrik.global.common.metrics.ImGlobalMetrics" init-method="init">
    ...
    <property name="reporterList">
        <util:list>
            <bean id="jmxReporter" class="com.imetrik.global.common.metrics.reporters.ImJmxReporter">
                <property name="registryId" value="metricRegistry1"/>
                <property name="durationUnit" value="SECONDS"/>
                <property name="rateUnit" value="SECONDS"/>
                <property name="domain" value="com.imetrik.global.metric"/>
            </bean>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The annotated beans is "jmxReporter".

But if I put it outside as a normal "first level" bean and use a reference instead, it is working.
But it is annoying! Is there a way to make it work even as a inner beans?